# setting up ssl on apache2

Tags: ssl, apache2

I'm having issues geting SSL running with apache2.

I've gone through a number of helpful articles:

- enabled ssl (sudo a2ensmod ssl)
- generated ssl certs
- generated a self-signed certificate (this is for
  testing)
- setup my default-ssl conf file
- enabled the conf file in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled as 000-default-ssl

  ```
  NameVirtualHost my.i.p.address 
  <VirtualHost my.i.p.address:443>
  DocumentRoot /var/www
  SSLEngine on
  #SSLOptions +StrictRequire
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.key
  ServerAdmin you@example.com
  ErrorLog /var/log/ssl_error_log
  TransferLog /var/log/ssl_access_log
  </VirtualHost>
  ```

I generated a symbolic link in sites-enabled (000-default-ssl) to my default-ssl conf file in sites-available

I'm getting the following error in Firefox: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long
My apache error log has a line: Invalid method in request \x16\x03

port 443 is open and listening because I can hit http://my.IP.Address:443 without errors.

So it looks like my server is listening to port 443, but it's serving up content unsecured (HTTP) which leads me to believe I've got an error in my VirtualHost conf but I can't find it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens when you try `https://...`?

Comment: @Pekka -- in FF, I get Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long

Comment: looking at the error, it points to apache not picking up on my default-ssl, suggesting that it's not been enabled

Comment: going into this further -- i've double-checked the conf file is enabled. I've tried VirtualHost _default_:443 and VirtualHost *:443 -- neither have worked

Answer (score 2):

So, the fix was to add ports to all the `NameVirtualHost` declarations in my `.conf` files:

```
NameVirtualHost my.i.p.address:443
```